# I am trying to fill in the reset option but i do not how to make it blank in default

Tags: powerapps

I wanted to ask about the radio buttons. Suppose I have a product to test "Radio1" and "Radio2". I select "Radio1" and based on that I have multiple radio buttons but I want them to be blank. Any ideas?

Comment: So do you have multiple radio buttons on same page/Screen or you have another screen for multiple radio buttons. Also few screenshot of your desired result could be of help for more understanding

Comment: Hi i tried doing it but it did not work.
So, i have one small form where i have a radio button named Abrasive and Polish, i select one of them and based on that appears few more radio buttons in another form, so basically if i try to select the radio button while i am on Abrasive and then i switch to polish the results in the radio remains the same. I wanted it to go to its default values that is null?

Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest setting the OnSelect property of Radio1. You can set OnSelect = `Reset(Radio2); Reset(Radio3)` etc. and then make sure that the Reset property of Radio2 and Radio3 is `false`.

If you want to conditionally show/hide the child radio buttons you can set their Visible property = `Radio1.Selected.Value = 1` where "1" is the first option in Radio1.

Here is what I described:
[image: Here is an example:]

Comment: Hi i tried doing it but it did not work.
So, i have one small form where i have a radio button named Abrasive and Polish, i select one of them and based on that appears few more radio buttons in another form, so basically if i try to select the radio button while i am on Abrasive and then i switch to polish the results in the radio remains the same. I wanted it to go to its default values that is null?

Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

**RadioButton1:**

`Items`: `["Abrasive", "Polish"]`

`OnSelect`:

```
Set(varResetAll, true);
Set(varResetAll, false);
Set(varResetAll, true)
```

**RadioButton2 and RadioButton3:**

`Reset`: `varResetAll`

[image]

Comment: Can i ask one more thing? Suppose i have numbers in the radio buttons ["1","2","3,"4"] which gets stored in the database as an integer but i do not want to show the numbers in the radio buttons but it will save the number in the database anyhow? Any suggestions?